# Trying to query firebase using where array-contains, how to wait for data to be received?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

I am using VueJS in my first real life webdev project, and am having trouble trying to query Firebase's firestore. I am using VueFire plugin for Vue FYI. I have users in a 'Patient' collection in firebase, and can access this list of patients by using the following query:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();

export default {
  ...
  data () {
    return {
      email: firebase.auth().currentUser.email,
      therapistData: [],
      patientsList: []
    }
  },
  firestore () {
    return {
      therapistData: db.collection('Therapist').doc(this.email),
      patientsList: db.collection('Patient').where('practiceName', 'array-contains', 'TestPractice')
  }
}
```

Each patient contains an array practiceName, and each therapist contains a string practiceName. patientsList should give me an object containing every patient in the Patient collection where their practiceName array contains the currently logged in user's (the Therapist) practiceName.

When hard coding in a string such as 'TestPractice' in my where query, the patientsList is populated as expected, and I can display it using the following vue code:

```
<div v-for="(userItem, idx) in patientsList) :key="idx">
  <p>{{ patientsList[idx].firstName }} {{ patientsList[idx].lastName }}</p>
</div>
```

So this code is all working properly. My issue is that I am trying to dynamically (based on the logged in Therapist) pull the practiceName value, and pass it as the third argument to my patientsList where query. So it should read:

```
patientsList: db.collection('Patient').where('practiceName', 'array-contains', this.therapistData.practiceName)
```

When I save this code, it gives me an error saying that where() expects a valid third argument, and got "undefined". Why is this undefined? When I render in vue `{{ therapistData.practiceName }}` or

```
<button @click="patientsList(therapistData.practiceName)">Test method</button>
...
methods: {
  patientsList: function(practice) {
    console.log('Practice: ' + practice)
  }
}
```

I can see the proper value of `therapistData.practiceName` print in the console. Can anyone please help me understand or fix this issue? Why is practiceName showing as undefined when trying to use it in my where() query?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to do programmatic binding

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      therapistData: [],
    }
  },

  watch: {
    therapistData: {
      // call it upon creation too
      immediate: true,
      handler(therapistData) {
        this.$bind('practiseName', therapistData.practiseName)
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what this is doing? I'm having trouble understanding. Is this all the code I need, or do I need to add ```therapistData()``` to my ```created ()``` objected?

Comment: Sorry, just checked the comment now. No this is not all the code. It is just addition to what you already have.So you can add just the watch part of the thing above and try.


````watch: {
    therapistData: {
      // call it upon creation too
      immediate: true,
      handler(therapistData) {
        this.$bind('practiseName', therapistData.practiseName)
      },
    },
  },````